# jQuery: Get request (GET/POST) parameters from ajax request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using [jQueryUI dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) to open a modal form on my site.  The form has a hidden input to pass on an affiliate code that is passed in the query string, like

http://mydomain.com/page1_with_form?affiliate=Chuck%20Norris

http://mydomain.com/page2_with_form?affiliate=Chuck%20Berry

I am using a [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) to make grabbing the GET values easy.

Both of the 2 pages (page1_with_form and page2_with_form) load the same modal form my_affiliate_form.html in a dialog box.  I have no problem doing something like this on the my_affiliate_form.html page

```
var affiliate_code = $.query.get('affiliate');
if (!affiliate_code) affiliate_code = "None";
$('[name=hidden_affiliate_field]').val(affiliate_code);
```

This works just dandy, and my affiliate ends up being Chuck Norris and Chuck Berry.

The problem, is now I want to not only include the affiliate code from the query string, but also want to use a key that is representative of the page they loaded the form from, ie. page1_with_form and page2_with_form).  For page1, the key might be "Public" and for page2 maybe "Private", or something like that.

Now I want it where my hidden field has a value of "Public Chuck Norris" when hitting this page
http://mydomain.com/page1_with_form?affiliate=Chuck%20Norris
and "Private Chuck Norris" when hitting this page http://mydomain.com/page2_with_form?affiliate=Chuck%20Norris

I am loading the dialog contents like this:

```
$('#modal-form-holder').dialog({
          bgiframe:true,
          width:width,
          title: title,
          modal:true,
          resizable: false,
          closeOnEscape: true,
          draggable: false,
          autoOpen:false
 }).load("my_affiliate_form.html?affiliate_key=" + key, null, onComplete);
```

The value for key is getting filled in correctly, but if my_affiliate_form.html tries to grab the "affiliate_key" via $.query.get('affiliate_key') it is empty.  This is because the query plugin in inspecting window.location, which hasn't changed.

How can I grab the request paraemeter in my_affiliate_form.html that came in the ajax request?

Sorry for being so verbose, I just want to make my question as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value in your onComplete handler.  Something like:

```
$('#modal-form-holder').dialog({
          bgiframe:true,
          width:width,
          title: title,
          modal:true,
          resizable: false,
          closeOnEscape: true,
          draggable: false,
          autoOpen:false
 }).load("my_affiliate_form.html", null, function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
{
  onComplete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest, key);
});
```

Then, in onComplete (which should be defined to take all four parameters), fill the affiliate_key field with key.

Comment: Ok, the code for creating the dialog is inside another function.  One of the paramaters for that function is the callback, named onComplete.  So when I call this I do, `addModalForm(600, 200, "SomeTitle", url, onThisRequestComplete);`  The my_affiliate_form.html is not hard coded in the load, but instead uses the param for url. Do I have to use an anonymous function, or can I still do it my way?